# Which IDE should I use for this art project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, eclipse, opengl, cuda

I have an art project that will require processing a live video feed to use as the basis of a particle system, which will be rendered using OpenGL and projected on a stage. I have a CUDA enabled graphics card, and I was thinking it would be nice to be able to use that for the image and particle system processing.  This project only needs to run on my computer.

I am normally a C# asp.net Visual Studio kinda guy, but for this project I plan on using c++.  Should I do the work in Eclipse on Ubuntu or Visual Studio in Windows?

I realize this can be fairly arbitrary, but I wondering if one IDE/OS might be better suited for this kind of work than the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the CUDA or OpenGL support is concerned you are fine with either of them. The nVidia examples are also multiplatform.
The real question is if you plan on using any GUI Toolkit as there are a only a few choices that are really portable.
In the end I'd recommend going with what you feel more comfortable with or where you will have the biggest knowledge gain (if learning something is a goal of the project.).

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/)? This might just help shortcut to what you need.

Comment: No, I hadnt heard of it, but I am gonna check it out.

Comment: Dude.  OpenFrameworks looks awesome!  That is definitely in the same vein as this project I am working on.  Thanks for the link

Comment: Given it's a 'C++ toolkit for creative coding', would be good to know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Visual Studio.
I haven't heard about any IDE especially good for such tasks.
If you already know VS, I see no reason to learn anything else.

Answer (score 0):

While the [CUDA toolkit](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_learn.html) is cross-platform, i recommend Linux in this case:
The debugger is based on gdb and the usability of the gcc toolchain is just much better on *nixes. You also don't seem to have any windows specific dependencies.

Comment: What do you mean by "the usability of the gcc toolchain is just much better on *nixes"?  What is "*nixes"?  I assume linux/unix based OS's

Comment: What do you mean about the usability of the gcc toolchain?

Comment: On windows you either use gcc-tools via a graphical interface, i.e. have to figure out their way to pass flags etc. to the gcc tools, or use them on the commandline, which ain't fun on windows (using cygwin doesn't help with everything).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already familiar with Visual Studio you should probably stick with it. In addition, you'll be able to use the [Nexus](http://www.nvidia.com/nexus) debugger to debug both the OpenGL and CUDA components.